# POST data using $resource

Tags: angularjs

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rob_balfre/7QUUf/

How do you POST data (across domain) using $resource?

For example this curl writes to the API with no problem:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name": "Wobbly"}' http://192.168.91.20/api/food/
```

and the header response is:

```
HTTP/1.0 201 CREATED
Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2012 08:19:42 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.1
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,*
Location: http://localhost/api/food/15/
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I'm totally stuck on how to get angular to POST the same way.  This is my $resource, it's worth noting that 'get' works just fine:

```
angular.module('tastypieModule', ['ngResource']).
factory('FoodOptions', function($resource, $timeout) {
   var FoodOptions = $resource('http://testurl/api/:type',
        {type: 'food'},
        {
            get: {method: 'JSONP', params: {format: 'jsonp', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'}},
            update: {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
        }
    );

 return FoodOptions;
})
```

When I call update it just fails and I see this is the console network tab:

```
METHOD: OPTIONS 
STATUS: (canceled) Load cancelled
```

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle to demo the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rob_balfre/7QUUf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server you need to implement a Cross Origin Resource Sharing. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ and http://omarrr.com/cors-html5-approach-to-crossdomain-policies/ both have good articles about the topic. The HEAD request is coming from the browser to your server to check for the headers that contain (or in your case, don't contain) the CORS permissions. If you implement CORS on the server then you'll see the browser first make a HEAD request once to the server then after confirming the correct permissions it will make the POST.

Comment: I've changed the server to allow for 'XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS' - see updated question.  Still getting the same error.  Is there some extra step I need to make in Angular to get it to work?